# aligning two text divs left of an image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a page set up where i have text that looks, essentially like this

```
Team Name                                            My Team Name +-------------+
Division                                             Team Division|             |
Current Ranking                                                  5| Team Logo   |
Event                                          Event name and date| Here        |
Event Wins : 5        Event Scored : 16        Event Conceded : 13|             |
Match 1                Team 1 - team 1 score team 2 score - Team 2|             |
Match 2                Team 1 - team 1 score team 2 score - Team 2+-------------+
Etc
```

but what i end up with is this

```
Team Name             event wins : 5                 My Team Name +-------------+
Division              event scored : 16              Team Division|             |
Current Ranking       Event                            event     5| Team Logo   |
conceded : 3                                   Event name and date| Here        |
                                                                  |             |
                                                                  +-------------+
Etc
```

I've tried playing with various float / clear combinations on various elements, but i'm struggling to see where i'm going wrong, so is it possible for someone to advise me on what's wrong with my html/css, and more importantly, why it's wrong, so i can more fully understand float etc to prevent these problems in the future.  thanks

Here's the jsfiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/LEaa9/1/

and the fullscreen results

http://jsfiddle.net/LEaa9/1/embedded/result/

Comment: Can u simulate the same on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Please provide a working example and remove all unnecessary clutter from your CSS (background-cradients).

Comment: sorry, you're right i should have used jsfiddle to give the example.  i've created a jsfiddle page and updated the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text at the bottom is coming up to the top because there's currently a gap between your two floated elements. Text will wrap around floated elements as long as there is room If you made them both 50% in width that would solve the problem. Also, floated elements should always have a width.

Another fix would be to add a style of `clear: both;` to the bottom text wrapper like so.

```
<div style="clear: both;">
  <div>event wins : 5</div>
  <div>event scored : 16</div>
  <div>event conceded : 3</div>
</div>
```

This ensures that this div will not sit inline with any floated elements, it will instead sit underneath them.

You should probably do both of the above for safety.

Comment: Thank you, that was the critical piece of info i must have missed when reading about floating.  Now i understand what i was doing wrong, i've been able to modify my styles and html to flow correctly

Answer (score 0):

First:
Too much `<div>` kill the `<div>`.

Second:
You would have to play with your `float:left`,  `float:right`, your display style (`display:block`) and the `width` of your page.

Here is what I have done with your code and it is displaying as you ask, feel free to use it but I would Highly suggeste that you make it your owne so you would understand what everything does:

```
<div style="background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(137,137,137,0.5) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(137,137,137,0.5))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(137,137,137,0.5) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(137,137,137,0.5) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(137,137,137,0.5) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(137,137,137,0.5) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff',    endColorstr='#80898989',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */">
<div style="margin-left:5px; display:block; width:900px;">
    <img src="/images/teams/logos/nexus.png" alt="Team Logo" style="float:right;width:239px;height:100%">
    <div style="background-color:red; float:left;width:600px;">
        <div style="display:block; float:left;">Team Name</div>
        <div style="display:block; float:right;">My Team</div>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color:green; float:left;width:600px;">
        <div style="display:block; float:left;">Division</div>
        <div style="display:block; float:right;">Elite Division</div>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color:blue; float:left;width:600px;">
        <div style="display:block; float:left;">Current Ranking</div>
        <div style="display:block; float:right;">1</div>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color:yellow; float:left;width:600px;">
        <div style="display:block; float:left;">Event</div>
        <div style="display:block; float:right;">CPPS Round 2     12/05/2013</div>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color:pink; float:left;width:600px;">
        <div style="display:block; float:left;width:200px; text-align:left;">event wins : 5</div>
        <div style="display:block; float:left;width:200px; text-align:center;">event scored : 16</div>
        <div style="display:block; float:left;width:200px; text-align:right;">event conceded : 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have colored the `<div>` for visibilty.